# 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:14:1: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
import 'asset_manifest.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:32:31: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
AssetManifest assetManifest = AssetManifest();
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have run flutter pubupgrade, flutter clean and pub get againt to try and clear the cache but the error still persist

i expected the program to run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update your google_fonts: package in pubspec.yaml to the [latest version](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts)

Check this url for more information :
https://dev.to/curtlycritchlow/how-to-fix-assetmanifest-is-imported-from-both-packageflutter-and-packagegooglefonts-error-28e8